# nodejs/mongodb - reading out one specific element

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to read out one specific element out of mongodb

```
db.collection('profiles', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne({'email': mail}, function(err, item) {
```

this reads the whole entry
for example:

```
{
  "email" : "asdd@asd.de",
  "password" : "asd",
  "_id" : ObjectId("51c8790f912501e403000001")
}
```

how can i read out only one of those elements
for example password

```
{
  "password" : "asd"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
collection.findOne({'email': mail}, {password: 1, _id: 0}, function(err, item) {
}
```

The second argument to `find`/`findOne` is the fields to select(projection). 
`{_id: 0}` is explicitly required because by default `_id`s are always returned.